# Using property attributes to define which JsonConverter to use

Tags: c#, json.net, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a need to specify a `JsonConverter` for properties which are decorated with a specific attribute, in this case `[DataType(DataType.PostalCode)]`.

I already have a custom `JsonConverter` for which I have set the `CanConvert` method as follows:

```
public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType) => objectType == typeof(string);
```

How can I make sure the `PostcodeJsonConverter` is used instead when the API encounters a `PostalCode` property?

```
[DataType(DataType.PostalCode)]
public string Postcode { get; set; }
```

I've tried the following but I suspect the `DataType` attribute is not available at this point.

```
public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType) => 
    objectType == typeof(string) && 
    objectType.GetCustomAttributes(true)
              .OfType<DataTypeAttribute>()
              .Any(dta => dta.DataType == DataType.PostalCode);
```

Do I need to decorate my model as follows instead?

```
[DataType(DataType.PostalCode)]
[JsonConverter(typeof(PostcodeJsonConverter))]
public string Postcode { get; set; }
```

Comment: Simply, yes. To use a custom JSON converter, you need to add the `JsonConverter` attribute to the property. JSON.NET has no ability to use attributes like `DataType` to guess which converter you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make a custom `ContractResolver` that looks for your `DataType` attribute on each property and maps the values to the appropriate converter.  Here is the code you would need:

```
public class DataTypeResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{
    private Dictionary<DataType, JsonConverter> ConvertersByDataType { get; set; }

    public DataTypeResolver()
    {
        // Adjust this list to match your actual data types and converters
        ConvertersByDataType = new Dictionary<DataType, JsonConverter>
        {
            { DataType.PostalCode, new PostalCodeConverter() },
            { DataType.PhoneNumber, new PhoneNumberConverter() },
        };
    }

    protected override JsonProperty CreateProperty(MemberInfo member, MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
    {
        JsonProperty prop = base.CreateProperty(member, memberSerialization);
        var att = prop.AttributeProvider.GetAttributes(true).OfType<DataTypeAttribute>().FirstOrDefault();
        if (att != null)
        {
            JsonConverter converter;
            if (ConvertersByDataType.TryGetValue(att.DataType, out converter))
            {
                prop.Converter = converter;
            }
        }
        return prop;
    }
}
```

Then pass the resolver to `SerializeObject` and/or `DeserializeObject` via the settings:

```
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    ContractResolver = new DataTypeResolver()
};
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(yourObject, settings);
```

Here is a working demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/k1kWv5

Answer (score 1):

You can add Converters to the JsonSerializerSettings. So instead of decorating everything, you may as well add your PostcodeJsonConverter there (depending on how often it is used, a decorator may be better though):

For aspnet core defaults:

`services.AddMvc().AddJsonOptions(o => o.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(new PostcodeJsonConverter()))`

For JsonConvert:

```
JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj, new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    Converters = { new PostcodeJsonConverter() }
});
```

Comment: yes but wouldnt this add it for all strings? the main issue isnt adding the JsonSerializer but only using it when the property is a postalcode

Comment: Your attribute check in `CanConvert` should work just fine.